# Unable to retrieve JSON value from PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have the following JSON below that I want to parse and get the value of the `TotalRows`. However, in my PHP and JavaScript it returns an error or undefined when I try to access it and I am not sure why.

---

For JavaScript:

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($customers); ?>;
console.log(data.TotalRows)
```

I even placed `console.log(data)` and it gave me the JSON I posted and then I did `console.log(data[0].TotalRows)` and it give me undefined.

---

My code for PHP is, where `$customers` returns the JSON below:

```
$customers = $customerDB->findCustomer(5, 1);
$arr = json_decode($customers, true);
echo $arr["TotalRows"];
```

---

```
[
   {
      "TotalRows":91,
      "Rows":[
         {
            "CompanyName":"Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados",
            "ContactName":"Ana Trujillo",
            "ContactTitle":"Owner",
            "City":"M\u00e9xico D.F.",
            "Country":"Mexico"
         },
         {
            "CompanyName":"Antonio Moreno Taquer\u00eda",
            "ContactName":"Antonio Moreno",
            "ContactTitle":"Owner",
            "City":"M\u00e9xico D.F.",
            "Country":"Mexico"
         },
         {
            "CompanyName":"Around the Horn",
            "ContactName":"Thomas Hardy",
            "ContactTitle":"Sales Representative",
            "City":"London",
            "Country":"UK"
         },
         {
            "CompanyName":"Berglunds snabbk\u00f6p",
            "ContactName":"Christina Berglund",
            "ContactTitle":"Order Administrator",
            "City":"Lule\u00e5",
            "Country":"Sweden"
         },
         {
            "CompanyName":"Blauer See Delikatessen",
            "ContactName":"Hanna Moos",
            "ContactTitle":"Sales Representative",
            "City":"Mannheim",
            "Country":"Germany"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: `data[0].totalRows` - you have an array around your object.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol It still gives me undefined :(

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I put `console.log(data)` and it gave me the JSON I posted and then I did `console.log(data[0].TotalRows)` and it give me undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I figured it out. The following worked:

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($customers); ?>;
var data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data[0].TotalRows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its an array of object, so you would get TotalRows by

```
  console.log(data[0].TotalRows);
```

Comment: It still gives me undefined

Comment: Did you parse your json in JS ? if not , please do the needful as 
var data = JSON.parse(data);
 console.log(data[0].TotalRows);